# MacOS crashed and now Postgres will not connect

Tags: postgresql, macos

Earlier today, I was developing my Postgres database, when my Mac crashed. When I restarted, I tried to start my server back up but psql refused with the error:

> psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
> Is the server running locally and accepting     connections on Unix
> domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I've tried full reboot and I tried uninstalling/reinstalling/restarting via homebrew but still get the same problem. I've looked through a few other posts to see if anything would help. The most I can tell is that somehow Postgres can't find the config-file possibly. Sorry, I'm not super experienced with cli and unix so I'm essentially flying around blind here.

**Small Update**
I tried a few more things to see if access the postgres file directly and still got an error.

> postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres postgres: could not access
> directory "/usr/local/var/postgres": No such file or directory

Not sure if I'm even looking in the right space at this point.

Comment: 1) Define crashed 2) Have you tried `brew services start postgresql`? If so and it failed what where the complete error messages?

Answer (score 1):

After numerous tries at reinstalling Postgres through homebrew, apparently one took. The only difference was I hard stopped (via homebrew) postgres before uninstalling/reinstalling.